# How to focus an input field that is in another component?

Tags: angular

In Component1 I have the following form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="formMain">
  <mat-form-field appearance="legacy">
    <mat-label>Title</mat-label>
    <input id="title" matInput formControlName="title">
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

In Component2 I have the following hyperlink:

```html
<a id="error-title" (click)="jumpToError($event)" href="">Title</a> is not specified.
```

```js
jumpToError(event: Event): void {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ((event.target as Element).id == 'error-title') {
    // Jump to error
  }
}
```

If the user clicks on that hyperlink, I want the input field to be focused. I don't know how to focus it since it is in another component. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. modify Component1

> `<input id="title" matInput #search formControlName="title">`
>
> `@ViewChild('search') searchElement: ElementRef;`
>
> ```
> focus(){
>     this.searchElement.nativeElement.focus();
> }
> ```

2. Add output to Component2

> ```
> @Output() jumpToError = new EventEmitter();
> ```

3. in parent component

> `@ViewChild(Component1) private component1: Component1;`
>
> ```
> focus() {
>     this.component1.focus();
> }
> ```
>
> <component2 (jumpToError)="focus()">